# Selecting elements in list Python

Tags: python, list, date

I am trying to select elements in a list containing the number of days in each month and add those days onto a variable containing a total.

```
from datetime import date
months = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
inmonth = str(float(input("month")))
intmonth = int(inmonth[0])
nowmonth = (date.today().month)
days = 0

if intmonth < nowmonth:
    for c in range(months[intmonth-1], months[nowmonth-1]):
        days = days + months[c]
print(days)
```

EDIT:

Ok, I fixed the issue with the input, however with this code nothing is being added to days, any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: Try ```months[int('03')]```.

Comment: are you tying to calculate the amount of days between two dates?

Comment: try this: `days = days + monthsrev[int(c)]`

Comment: Yes, this is just a snippet of the code for if the year entered is larger than the current year. I am doing it without using date(a)-date(b) function.

Comment: `date.today().month` returns an integer already, but January is 1 (not 0).`date.today().month - 1` should be enough to index the list properly. If you have a `date` instance (parsed from your date string with strttime), month will be an int. Just substract `1` from that number and you'll get the index you need.

Comment: @user2975192: Please write up what you have found as a solution to your question and accept it. Many other people will have a similar problem, and SO wouldn't exist if every satisfied customer left without a trace

Comment: to count numbers of days  beetwen the first day in the user-specified month and the first day in the current month: `first = date.today().replace(day=1);` `days = (first - first.replace(month=int(input('month')))).days` (both dates are assumed to be in the current year)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem stated by Kieleth, your loop does not use the indices you expected.
 We are now in october (`nowmonth = 10`), say I answer `4` for april.

```
for c in range(months[intmonth-1], months[nowmonth-1]):
```

gives `intmonth-1 = 3`, **`months[intmonth-1] = 30`**, `nowmonth-1 = 9`, **`months[nowmonth-1] = 31`** => `c` gets the value `30` !!!

So you code should be :

```
from datetime import date
months = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
intmonth = int(input("month")) # fixes the problem stated by Kieleth
nowmonth = (date.today().month)
days = 0

if intmonth < nowmonth:
    for c in range(intmonth-1, nowmonth-1):
        days = days + months[c]
print(days)
```

But the method to find those kind or errors if quite simple : *print is your friend* !!!

If you simply had written:

```
from datetime import date
months = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
inmonth = str(float(input("month")))
intmonth = int(inmonth[0])
print(inmonth, intmonth) # control input
nowmonth = (date.today().month)
days = 0

if intmonth < nowmonth:
    for c in range(months[intmonth-1], months[nowmonth-1]):
        print (c, days) # a spy per iteration
        days = days + months[c]
print(days)
```

it would have been evident that you did not go through the loop